M1 macbook air - Karabiner elements - can't find § key that I wish to void as the key is stuck down (metaphor§ically)§§§§
I have got a 4 year old mac and the line of numbers keys seem to be failing.
I have used Karabiner Elements to remap f3 to 3 and void 3. I had thought the problem was over use given the # and £ symbols.
I am now having the same §§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ problem with that key, which I never use.
I cannot find it on the settings page in Karabiner Elements, despite looking a few times.
Any ideas? Perhaps I'm just not seeing it, or there is a key code I could use.
Thanks
I Have searched here and the web, I have tried to explore settings, already.
